# Bookmark to check published date

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarks

Do anyone of you know how to make a Bookmark to check the website published date.
What I actually want is to go to a website and press this bookmark and in the bookmark is something like this.

google.com/search?q=inurl:{{***website url of active page***}}&as_qdr=y15

This way you can check via google whats the publish date of a website.

Is there somekind of javascript code that copy's the website's url to make this happen?

Comment: I doubt any browsers support such a feature. You would be better off creating an extension for chrome/firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out on my own. I use this code to get to see the publish date in google.

You can save it as Bookmark to check.

It comes very handy to fill your APA details.

javascript:void(location.href='http://google.com/search?q=inurl:'+escape(location.href))+'&as_qdr=y15'